# Conditional group by join in R

Tags: r, join, conditional-statements

I am new to R and rather flumoxed by the following problem. I have two vectors of dates (the vectors are not necessarily aligned, nor of the same length).

I want to find for each date in the first vector the next date in the second vector.

```
vecA <- as.Date(c('1951-07-01', '1953-01-01', '1957-04-01', '1958-12-01',
       '1963-06-01', '1965-05-01'))
vecB <- as.Date(c('1952-01-12', '1952-02-01', '1954-03-01', '1958-08-01', 
           '1959-03-01', '1964-03-01', '1966-05-01'))
```

In SQL I would write something like this, but I cannot find any tips in SO as to how to do this in R.

```
 select vecA.Date, min(vecB.Date)
       from vecA inner join vecB
       on vecA.Date < vecB.Date
       group by vecA.Date
```

The output should look like this:

```
Start      End
1951-07-01 1952-01-12
1953-01-01 1954-03-01
1957-04-01 1958-08-01
1958-12-01 1959-03-01
1963-06-01 1964-03-01
1965-05-01 1966-05-01
```

Comment: So, for `vecA[1]` the proper date would be `vecB[1]`, and for `vecA[2]` the proper date would be `vecB[3]`?

Comment: Start             End
    1951-07-01 1952-02-01
    1953-01-01 1954-03-01
    1957-04-01 1958-08-01

Comment: I edited that into the answer since the comment preserves no formatting. But how does that logic work; shouldn't 1952-01-12 be the end date for the first one?

Comment: Yes. Sorry the above doesn't format well.  But yes. The left hand column in the resulting array will have all of vecA's dates, and the right hand column the minimum date from vecB that occurs after the date in column 1.

Comment: So the first one, 1951-07-01, should end with 1952-01-12 - just making sure, as you said 1952-02-01 in your comment. I can edit the question again if you confirm.

Comment: Absolutely. 1952-01-12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `data.table` rolling joins

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(vecA) ## convert to `data.table` object
dt2 <- as.data.table(vecB) ## convert to `data.table` object
setkey(dt2) # key in order to perform a binary join
res <- dt2[dt1, vecB, roll = -Inf, by = .EACHI] # run the inner join while selecting closest date 
setnames(res, c("Start", "End"))
res
#         Start        End
# 1: 1951-07-01 1952-01-12
# 2: 1953-01-01 1954-03-01
# 3: 1957-04-01 1958-08-01
# 4: 1958-12-01 1959-03-01
# 5: 1963-06-01 1964-03-01
# 6: 1965-05-01 1966-05-01
```

---

Alternatively, we can also do:

```
data.table(vecA=vecB, vecB, key="vecA")[dt1, roll=-Inf]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you are asking, but it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish and so this might not be the best way. In essence, this code first orders both vectors to ensure they are in the same ordering. Then, using a `for` loop, it loops over all the elements in `vecA` and uses `x < vecB` to find out which elements in `vecB` are less than `x`.

That is wrapped in `which`, which returns the numeric index of of each `TRUE` element of a vector, and then in `min` which gives the smallest numeric index. This is then used to subset `vecB` to return the date; it's all wrapped in `print` so you can see the output of the loop.

This is probably not the best way of doing this, but without more context on your goals it should at least get you started.

```
> vecA <- vecA[order(vecA)]
> vecB <- vecB[order(vecB)]
> for(x in vecA) {print(vecB[min(which(x < vecB))])}
[1] "1952-01-12"
[1] "1954-03-01"
[1] "1958-08-01"
[1] "1959-03-01"
[1] "1964-03-01"
[1] "1966-05-01"
```